# Tombstone cleanup failed with the exception "The current operation could not be completed because the database is not provisioned for sync

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

> Tombstone cleanup failed with the exception "The current operation could not be completed because the database is not provisioned for sync or you not have permissions to the sync configuration tables."

I got this Error while doing sync on Azure SQL database in Database Sync Group Action.

I solved this issue in the following way

Go to Your Database Sync Group Page, then follow these steps:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsI8g.png
**"Click on Database"**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeUcx.png
**"Click on Hub Database"**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqOnx.png
**"Enter Your SQL Server Username and Password and Save"**

Comment: It's nice of you to share your knowledge on StackOverflow. However, your question isn't really a question. Please edit it to make it more useful for others. Something like: *I got this error when I did this and that, how can I solve it? This is what I've tried.*

Answer (score 0):

Go to Your Database Sync Group Page, then follow the below steps:

**1. Click on Database**
[image]

**2. Click on Hub Database**

[image]

**3. Enter Your SQL Server Username and Password and Save**
[image]